# rollupjs and sapper - require is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, commonjs, rollupjs

i am using `sapper` und `svelte` with `rollupjs`. But when i try to use the repo [scrollscene](https://github.com/jonkwheeler/ScrollScene) from Github, i get an error on console when run `npm run dev`: `ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Here is my `rollup.config.js`

```js
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import builtins from 'rollup-plugin-node-builtins';
import globals from 'rollup-plugin-node-globals';
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import config from 'sapper/config/rollup.js';
import pkg from './package.json';

const mode = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const dev = mode === 'development';
const legacy = !!process.env.SAPPER_LEGACY_BUILD;

const onwarn = (warning, onwarn) => (warning.code === 'CIRCULAR_DEPENDENCY' && /[/\\]@sapper[/\\]/.test(warning.message)) || onwarn(warning);

export default {
    client: {
        input: config.client.input(),
        output: config.client.output(),
        plugins: [
            replace({
                'process.browser': true,
                'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(mode)
            }),
            svelte({
                dev,
                hydratable: true,
                emitCss: true
            }),
            resolve({
                browser: true,
                preferBuiltins: true,
                dedupe: ['svelte']
            }),
            commonjs(),
            globals(),
            builtins(),
            legacy && babel({
                extensions: ['.js', '.mjs', '.html', '.svelte'],
                runtimeHelpers: true,
                exclude: ['node_modules/@babel/**'],
                presets: [
                    ['@babel/preset-env', {
                        targets: '> 0.25%, not dead'
                    }]
                ],
                plugins: [
                    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
                    ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime', {
                        useESModules: true
                    }]
                ]
            }),

            !dev && terser({
                module: true
            })
        ],

        onwarn,
    },

    server: {
        input: config.server.input(),
        output: config.server.output(),
        plugins: [
            replace({
                'process.browser': false,
                'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(mode)
            }),
            svelte({
                generate: 'ssr',
                dev
            }),
            resolve({
                dedupe: ['svelte']
            }),
            commonjs()
        ],
        external: Object.keys(pkg.dependencies).concat(
            require('module').builtinModules || Object.keys(process.binding('natives'))
        ),

        onwarn,
    },

    serviceworker: {
        input: config.serviceworker.input(),
        output: config.serviceworker.output(),
        plugins: [
            resolve(),
            replace({
                'process.browser': true,
                'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(mode)
            }),
            commonjs(),
            !dev && terser()
        ],

        onwarn,
    }
};
```

I tried to add the packages: `rollup-plugin-node-builtins` and `rollup-plugin-node-globals`, but nothing changed. The developer of [scrollscene](https://github.com/jonkwheeler/ScrollScene) send me a link to a [similiar issue](https://github.com/epranka/scrollmagic-plugin-gsap/issues/9), but i couldn't solve the problem with this.

What's going wrong here and how can i solve this, so i can use this library? Thanks for your answer and for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Niklas,

I had the same problem, and what I had to do was do the `require` inside of a `.js` file instead of in the `.svelte` file.

EDIT:
[This is the reference I had](https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper-template/tree/master/src/routes/blog). The posts in the blog example of the `sapper-template` project [on GitHub](https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper-template)